# Add Secondary IP Address That Is Seen By A Server

Tags: networking

I need to add another IP address and I need the server to be able to know see it. 
On the client: curl using the second IP/interface
On the server: netstat or tcpdump

I want to be able to see the second IP address in the server.

Tried ip link add, ip address add, ifconfig. Nothing works. On the server there is always the "main" address of the client.

Everything is on the LAN, no need for DNS, etc..

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution as `ip` isn't persistent:

```
sudo nmcli con modify "interface_name" +ipv4.addresses 172.16.2.140/24
sudo nmcli con up "interface_name"
```

Note you change that ip add I added to yours and do this on the client machine.

Comment: so if you ping that ip add what happens?

Comment: Pinging works. It also works with other methods. Thats because the icmp that asks "who has the_new_address".

Comment: Did you restart the networkmanager on the server?

Comment: Also try to ping the client from the server!

Comment: veth works. Just had an error with that :(